# Programatically create bean in spring-boot to update class in jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring-boot application that does not use applicationContext.xml, a bean is needed to update a field of a class that exists in a jar file used by the application.
If the application used applicationContext.xml, the bean could be specfied as follows:

```
<bean id="au" class="path1.path2.path3.AU">

    <property name="property1" value="newValue" />

</bean>
```

How can the above bean be created programmatically in java?

Comment: You can use @ Bean annotation above a method that returns an object of path1.path2.path3.AU. The class in which that method resides must be annotated with @ Configuration and must be scanned by Spring Boot.

Comment: @Bean (name="au") 
    path1.path2.path3.AU getAU() {
        path1.path2.path3.AU aux = ....
        aux.setProperty1("newValue");
        return aux;
    }  Something like the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify it in a @Bean annotated method in your @SpringBootApplication class at it's simplest:

```
import path1.path2.path3.AU;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) { ... }

  // This method will produce a bean named "au" of class AU
  @Bean
  public AU au() {
    AU au = new AU();
    au.setProperty1("newValue");
    return au;
  }
}
```

This is not really specific to Spring Boot but more of pure Spring features. You can [review the docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java).